# typescript : how generate this in javascript

Tags: typescript

I try to write something in typescript which can have this result in javascript.
It's for a NodeJS serveur which work with controllers imported at start

(This is Javascript result, my goal)
How can I write this?

```js
'use strict';

module.exports.AuthLogin = async (ctx, next) => {


    await next();
};
```

EDIT : ----------

The router of NodeJS load function with a swagger documentation.

```
/auth/login:
 post:
  tags:
  - "Auth"
  operationId: "authLoginPOST"
  ...
```

The documentation give the path of javascript file and function name

```
case 'post':
     router.post(url, controller);
```

So in exemple :
url = tags
controller = operationId

> router.post("Auth", authLoginPOST);

That is how the routing is made.

My goal is to use the same method, and have some generate final code which is like my first exemple.

Comment: Not sure what the question is? Your code seems valid Typescript, after it is compiled you should be able to invoke `apiTest` from JavaScript without a problem. What isn't working?

Comment: This is a javascript controllers. So it's the result and not yet typescript.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, I have no idea what types `ctx` or `next()` should be, but it could be something like this:

```
interface Context { }

type Next = () => void;

export async function apiTest(ctx: Context, next: Next): Promise<void> {
    await next();
}
```

Comment: Yes sorry.  ctx it's the context of nodeJS router (in koa) so generally the data of my API, body etc...  next is the task I think. It's about koa generally

Answer (score 0):

In Typescript, code like this works as Koa-style middleware:

```
import {Context} from 'koa';

export async function apiTest(context: Context, next: () => Promise<any>) => {
  context.status = 200;
  await next();
});
```

Using `next()` isn't necessary unless you need to do some post-processing, for most routes you can go with the more simple:

```
import {Context} from 'koa';

export async function apiTest(context: Context) => {
  context.status = 200;
});
```

I'd further recommend using object destructuring:

```
import {Context} from 'koa';

export async function apiTest({
  params: {someId},
  request,
  response
}: Context) => {
  ...
  response.status = 200;
});
```